# Asking user input and return to question if wrong input is entered

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm stuck on a question for an assignment for school. Am i missing something with python

I am running my input's in a while loop and when a value error is thrown. I want to return to the last question asked. but every time it restarts from the beginning of the code.

```
while True:
    try:
        start_value = int(input('Enter a start value (Default: 0): ') or 0)
        end_value = int(input('Enter a end value: '))
        step_value = int(input('Enter step value (Default: 1): ') or '1')

    except ValueError:
        print('Numeric value only!')
        continue
    else:
        for x in range(start_value, end_value, step_value):
           print(str(x), end=' ')
    break
```

can anyone point me in the right direction. I have looked all over and only examples i can find are while loops only with one input in the try statement

Comment: What do you mean by the "last question asked". Do you mean the answers to the previous inputs?

Comment: You should have 3 `while` loops to only repeat the last failed question.

Comment: You could also initialize each variable to `None` before the loop. Then check if the value is `None` before asking them to enter the value.

Comment: in python can you not send it back to the input that throw the except?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `if` to control the flow?

```
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        if i==0:
            start_value = int(input('Enter a start value (Default: 0): ') or 0)
            i=1
        if i==1:    
            end_value = int(input('Enter a end value: '))
            i=2
        if i==2:
            step_value = int(input('Enter step value (Default: 1): ') or '1')

    except ValueError:
        print('Numeric value only!')
        continue
    else:
        for x in range(start_value, end_value, step_value):
           print(str(x), end=' ')
    break
```

Comment: Not a bad idea.